# Java ProcessBuilder: finds .cmd nad .exe but not .bat

Tags: java, external

As the title says, I'm using a basic ProcessBuilder:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(new String[] {this.getExecutable(), "--version"});
             pb.directory(pomDir);
             pb.redirectOutput(appendTo(log));
             Process p = pb.start();
             p.waitFor();
```

If getExecutable() is an .exe on the path (like Python.exe) or a .cmd (like npm.cmd), this works.

However, if it is a .bat (like mvn.bat), it does not.

Here are the relevant path entries:

```
c:\Python27;
c:\Users\Matt\Tools\apache-maven-3.3.9\bin;
c:\Users\Matt\Tools\node;
```

Output of python --version:

```
Python 2.7.10
```

Output of mvn --version:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Error running mvn init
        at tech.project.trait.act(act.java:81)
        at tech.project.admin.action.LastDependendantInvoker.invoke(LastDependendantInvoker.java:23)
        at tech.project.admin.command.NewAppCommand.execute(NewAppCommand.java:71)
        at tech.project.admin.command.init.InitCommand.execute(InitCommand.java:33)
        at tech.project.admin.CLI.main(CLI.java:83)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "mvn.bat" (in directory "c:\Users\Matt\Documents\Projects\foo"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
        at tech.project.trait.act(act.java:75)
        ... 4 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(Unknown Source)
        ... 6 more
```

If I attempt to wrap it in `cmd` I get:

```
cmd //C mvn --version
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.14393]
(c) 2016 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
```

From the commandline, mvn --version returns:

```
mvn --version
Apache Maven 3.3.9 (bb52d8502b132ec0a5a3f4c09453c07478323dc5; 2015-11-10T10:41:47-06:00)
Maven home: c:\Users\Matt\Tools\apache-maven-3.3.9
Java version: 1.8.0_73, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73\jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "dos"
```

Thoughts?

---

Based on @Adroidan's comments, I have tried:

```
"cmd.exe", "//C",  "\""+this.getExecutable()+" --version\""
```

But that seems to spawn a new cmd shell, and print the cmd.exe version:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.14393]
(c) 2016 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
```

From the commandline, the equivallent works fine:

```
$ cmd.exe //C "mvn --version"
Apache Maven 3.3.9 (bb52d8502b132ec0a5a3f4c09453c07478323dc5; 2015-11-10T10:41:47-06:00)
Maven home: C:\Users\Matt\Tools\apache-maven-3.3.9
Java version: 1.8.0_73, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73\jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "dos"
```

Comment: Try using a single forward slash: `cmd /c mvn --version`

Answer (score 5):

Here are the basics:

- for bat files, the executable should be `"cmd.exe"`
- the argument is the bat plus its arguments as a single string, eg `"mvn --version"`
- add `"/C"` so the `cmd` shell doesn't keep running

so your code should look like this:

```
new ProcessBuilder().command("cmd.exe", "/C", "mvn --version")
```

(although you may need to fully qualify the path to `mvn`)

---

Here's a complete minimal working example:

Create a file `c:\tools\test.bat` with this content:

```
@echo off
echo I was passed: %1
```

Then, running this:

```
Process p = new ProcessBuilder().command("cmd.exe", "/C", "/tools/test.bat foo").start();
p.waitFor();
System.out.println(new Scanner(p.getInputStream()).useDelimiter("\\A").next());
```

Produces this:

```
I was passed: foo
```

Comment: great answer.  What got me was maven had changed from a .bat to .cmd file in a minor release...

Answer (score 2):

a .bat is not an executable since it is not compiled.

Would probably need more information on what you are trying to do in order to be of any more help. You would likely need to wrap the command in cmd.exe which is the shell that a batch file can actually be run in.

Comment: I tried wrapping it in a cmd like so: `"cmd", "//C",  this.getExecutable(), "--version"` but I got this output: `Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.14393]
(c) 2016 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.`, apparently some win shell dressing...

Comment: Right that is the version of CMD.exe.

Not sure why you are trying to get the version of a batch file because they don't have one. The batch file is not compiled so it doesn't have the same set of properties.

Comment: Ah I see what you are saying.  I'm just using mvn --version to test access to the maven command (instead of mvn install or something, they have same results as --version, command not found).

Comment: That was a big hint, lead to me to try: `cmd.exe //C "mvn --version"` which works from the commandline at least